# Video Playing when runing the app directly from eclipse but when installed otherwise it doesnot play

Tags: android, video, splash-screen

In an app, I have a splash screen which plays a video and after the video finishes,it loads the next page. It works fine when I run the build on a mobile or emulator connected to the system. But the problem is that when I install the build in my mobile by mail or by some other way, the Video does not shows up(SPLASH Screen), instead it goes to the next page.

I am bit confussed about the real issue behind this behaviour as when run on emulator it works fine, also when running on a mobile using usb.

Comment: We can't help without code! Does LogCat provide any info about errors maybe?

Comment: check the manifest for launcher activity. is it splash activity or the "next page" activity?

Comment: Manifest's launcher activity is correctely done...also it doesnot give any errors...actually only after the video completes,i have coded to go to the next page.So that means the video is completing but not showing.And its workin fine in emulator..also when i run the build on mobile directly from eclipse

Comment: Did you sent absolutelty same .apk file via email or what ever else? And what about Android versions: there is very big difference in video files format support between 2.3 and 4.0.x versions. Maybe it just can't be played because of Os version.